# ShiftVector not wrapped around-cells showing zeroes

Tags: vba

I'm currently working on this vba programming question.
[image]

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Option Base 1

Function ShiftVector(rng As Range, n As Integer) As Variant
    
    Dim A() As Variant, B() As Variant
    Dim nr As Integer, i As Integer
    
    nr = rng.Rows.Count
    ReDim A(nr, 1) As Variant
    ReDim B(nr, 1) As Variant
    
    A = rng
    
    For i = 1 To nr - n
        If i <= (nr - n) Then
            B(i, 1) = A(i + n, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    For i = (nr - n + 1) To nr
        If i <= nr Then
            B(i, 1) = A(i - nr + n, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    ShiftVector = B
    
End Function
```

When n=3, the top 3 items cannot be wrapped down to the bottom. Instead, 0s are showing in the bottom three cells.
[image]

Here is the flowchart to the problem.
[image]

Any assistance will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.  Bottom 3 cells came back with 1, hi & 5.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Function ShiftVector(rng As Range, n As Integer) As Variant
    
    Dim A As Variant, B As Variant
    Dim nr As Long, i As Long, pos As Long
    
    A = rng.Value
    nr = UBound(A, 1)
    ReDim B(1 To nr, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To nr
        pos = IIf(i > n, i - n, (nr - n) + i)
        B(pos, 1) = A(i, 1)
    Next i
    ShiftVector = B
End Function
```

FYI I would avoid `Option Base 1` in VBA - the default base is zero and it's best to leave it at that. And `Option Base 1` has no impact on the base of an array obtained using `someRange.Value` (always 1)

Answer (score 0):

Running your code, it works nicely for values between 0 to the number of rows of rng (including `n`=3. However, it fails for values of `n` > `nr` and also `n` < 0 (negative), which is important if the user of your function needs to shift the vector down by `n` positions.

I also have to admit that I struggled to understand the logic of your algorithm and why you need 2 loops to perform the task (entirely a failure on my part).

Edit:

I completely undertand the logic of your algorithm now with the aid of your nice flow-chart. I don't see why it wouldn't work for you, it works well on my computer for 0 <= `n` <= `nr`.

End of Edit

In situations like this using `Mod` seems like the most natural option to me. It accounts for all values of `n` nicely (positive, negative or zero)

Here is a working code. If you want to build your own algorithm, then look away now :)

Please note the use of `Long` wherever one might be tempted to use `Integer`, but obviously you should change it if it is a requirement of the question.

```
Function ShiftVector(rng As Range, n As Long) As Variant
    
  Application.Volatile
  
  Dim aResult() As Variant
  Dim vRng As Variant
  Dim lRows As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim i_new As Long
  
  vRng = rng.Value ' Process vector more efficiently
  lRows = rng.Rows.Count ' Don't use Ubound(vRng) here
  ReDim aResult(1 To lRows, 1 To 1)
  
  If lRows = 1 Then
    ' vRng is simply the value of the cell (not array of values)
    ' You'll get an error in you try something like vRng(i, 1)
    aResult(1, 1) = vRng
  Else
    For i = 1 To lRows
      ' This is the transformation rule.
      ' Using Mod is the most natural way in this case
      ' and works for all values of n (+, - and 0).
      ' iRows * Abs(n) ensures (i - n + iRows * Abs(n)) > 0
      i_new = (i - n + lRows * Abs(n)) Mod lRows
      
      ' If n is a multiple of iRows then i_new=0
      If i_new = 0 Then i_new = lRows
      
      ' Perform transformation
      aResult(i_new, 1) = vRng(i, 1)
    Next i
  End If
  
  ShiftVector = aResult
End Function
```